# Cannot update MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am struggling to update my MySQL database.
This is what I have written:

```
$mysql_link = mysql_connect('servername','username','password');
mysql_select_db('bambi4couk_599731_db3', $mysql_link);

$serializedTemplates = serialize($_SESSION['data']['user']['templates']);
mysql_query("UPDATE rmusers SET templates='$serializedTemplates' WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email'] . "'");
```

How can I fix this to make it work?

**EDIT:**

I am not getting an error but the function is not updating the database and it is returning false.

$_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email'] returns the email address used (which does appear in the database).

The serialized array is too long to paste here but there are no problems with it - it is a string anyway so I don't see how it could be wrong.

**EDIT2:**

As it turned out my assumption was wrong, the serialized array had to be escaped first.

Comment: What error are you getting?  The query itself looks sound so some information will be needed.  Dumps of `$serialiszedTemplates` and `$_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email']` could be handy too.  (p.s. much better on the login details this time ;) )

Comment: thanks (rather embarrassing). I am not getting an error the function is just doing nothing and returning false. $_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email'] returns the email address used (which does appear in the database) and the serialized array is too long to paste here but there are no problems with it - it is a string anyway so I don't see how it could be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried doing a manual update using the ['email'] value?  It sounds as though it's the WHERE criteria at fault as otherwise it would be updating at least *something*, or erroring.  Might be worth adding the error handler as detailed by bumperbox in case an error is being supressed

Comment: thanks for your help. as it turned out my mistake was more basic than you could have expected. I had not escaped the serialized array - it is now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 or die (mysql_error());
```

Like this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE rmusers SET templates='$serializedTemplates' WHERE email='" . $_SESSION['data']['user']['details']['email'] . "'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Then tell us what the error message is, so we can help you

At a guess I would expect you have not escaped the values

see mysql_real_escape_string()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: bingo. thank you for your help. I blame w3schools for my poor education.